# How to make subject field compulsory in Outlook 2007?

Tags: vba, outlook

I always forget to write subject in email, so I want make the subject field compulsory.
Can you help me please?

Comment: In what way is that a programming question? And perhaps you can correct your spelling a little bit :)

Comment: Yes, I don't doubt it. But in what way?

Comment: This question makes no sense. Either you doubt it or you don't. ;-) There is VBA code that solves the problem, so I guess it must be programming related.

Comment: Ah, VBA was the missing information. Don't know why I didn't thought of that... Sorry :)

Answer (score 2):

```
Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, ByRef Cancel As Boolean)

  If Item.Subject = "" Then
    Item.Subject = InputBox("Please do not always forget the subject!")
  End If

  If Item.Subject = "" Then
    MsgBox "Won't send this without a subject."
    Cancel = True
  End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Do While Item.Subject = ""
Item.Subject = InputBox("..")
Loop
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar routine which just checks if I mention the word attachment, and will prompt me if I want to cancel the send, and I have to put in the line:

Item.Display

so that I can go add the attachment.  This way you can just prompt with a messagebox saying to add the subject...